# Error: Time out while performing API call in Python

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I have a list (lst) which is a list of list. There are 19 elements in this list and each element has ~2500 strings.

```
lst

[['A', 'B', 'C',...]['E', 'F', 'G',....][.....]]
```

I am using these strings (A,B....) to call an API endpoint ('q':element). However after ~1800 strings, I am getting a time out.

I am running following lines of code.

```
def get_val(element):
    url = 'https://www.xxxx/yyy/api/search'
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    param = {'q': element, 'page' : 500}
    
    try:
        response = requests.get(url, headers = headers, params = param, timeout=(3.05, 27))
        docs = response.json()['response']['docs']
        
        for result in docs:
            file.write("%s\t%s\n" % (element,result['short_form']))
    
    except Timeout:
        print('Timeout has been raised.')

#loop through elements of list
for i in lst:
    for element in i:
        get_val(element)
```

How can I modify my code to avoid this time out?

Comment: Sounds like the timeout is deliberately caused by a server-side mechanism to protect the server against automated mass requests. You may want to add significant delays between calls.

Comment: The timeout has nothing to do with your code. It just means that the API is taking too long to respond

Comment: I know it has already been explained (it's very likely a server side protection mechanism) but I just want to add that you can debug this kind of issue by using curl or some similar HTTP client to prove it's not an issue with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason for this timeout could be a protection against mass requests, that means,  that there are too many requests in a short time.

To overcome this problem a short pause could be added after for example every 100 requests. However this is a try and error approach but it could work. Worst case would be to add a delay after every request.

```
import time

time.sleep(0.5)
```

The parameter is added in seconds so 0.5 sec for example.